# Tkinter Keyboard input slow

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, PhotoImage, TkVersion, Frame, Canvas

def up(event):
    w.move(car, 0, -10)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")

w = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)

img = PhotoImage(file="track.png")
track = w.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor='nw')

img_2 = PhotoImage(file="car.png")
car = w.create_image(380, 380, image=img_2, anchor='nw')

w.pack()
root.bind("<Up>", up)
root.mainloop()
```

I have a simple tkinter program here that moves a car image up the screen when the up arrow key is pressed. However, when I run the program, I can visibly see the lag, as each frame is animated one by one. I never had this kind of issue in other graphics programming like SDL in C++ - the movement was always very smooth. What could be going on here?

Comment: I see no lag with the code you've posted. For me, the car moves instantly.

Comment: `tkinter` is not `SDL` (or `PyGame` which use `SDL 1.2`) which name is `Simple DirectMedia Layer` and was created for direct access to media in games. Doc: [SDL-1.2.15](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using dictionary and `after`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, PhotoImage, TkVersion, Frame, Canvas

keys = {
    "U": False,
    "L": False,
    "D": False,
    "R": False
}

def up(event):
    keys["U"] = True

def noup(event):
    keys["U"] = False

def left(event):
    keys["L"] = True

def noleft(event):
    keys["L"] = False

def down(event):
    keys["D"] = True

def nodown(event):
    keys["D"] = False

def right(event):
    keys["R"] = True

def noright(event):
    keys["R"] = False

def move_car():
    if keys["U"]:
        w.move(car, 0, -5)
    if keys["L"]:
        w.move(car, -5, 0)
    if keys["D"]:
        w.move(car, 0, 5)
    if keys["R"]:
        w.move(car, 5, 0)
    root.after(10, move_car)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")

w = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)

img = PhotoImage(file="track.png")
track = w.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor='nw')

img_2 = PhotoImage(file="car.png")
car = w.create_image(380, 380, image=img_2, anchor='nw')

w.pack()
root.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", up)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>", noup)
root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>", left)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Left>", noleft)
root.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", down)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Down>", nodown)
root.bind("<KeyPress-Right>", right)
root.bind("<KeyRelease-Right>", noright)

root.after(0, move_car)

root.mainloop()
```